# PHP/SharePoint API, SAML and Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, sharepoint, saml

I have a lot of questions and things to know about how this works - for context I am a PHP/WordPress developer and Sharepoint is very new to me. I've always written PHP apps for the past few years and now we're moving to SharePoint and we're looking at writing PHP/WordPress applications but using the Office 365 authentication so that user logins will be standard across-the-board.

I came across this [API](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) but I couldn't get it work, as it looks like I need to take care of some authentication-related settings on the SharePoint Online side, which I have no idea where to find or how it works.

We've also found this [service](https://www.onelogin.com/) and this [WP plugin/service](https://auth0.com/authenticate/sharepoint/wordpress) which can probably do it for us but we'd think of preferring to make the API work instead of relying on a third-party authentication service.

I've been trying to get the phpSPO to work but I keep getting a "Could not resolve host: login.microsoftonline.com" error and there has been no response in their github site.
Complete error log:

This is the error log I'm getting:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not resolve host: login.microsoftonline.com' in /var/www/properties/web/artisspo/src/Runtime/Utilities/Requests.php:34\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/properties/web/spo/src/Runtime/Utilities/Requests.php(67): Office365\\PHP\\Client\\Runtime\\Utilities\\Requests::execute(Object(Office365\\PHP\\Client\\Runtime\\Utilities\\RequestOptions))\n#1 /var/www/properties/web/artisspo/src/Runtime/Auth/SamlTokenProvider.php(92): Office365\\PHP\\Client\\Runtime\\Utilities\\Requests::post('https://login.m...', NULL, '???<s:Envelope ...')\n#2 /var/www/properties/web/spo/src/Runtime/Auth/SamlTokenProvider.php(60): Office365\\PHP\\Client\\Runtime\\Auth\\SamlTokenProvider->acquireSecurityToken('test_user', '123456')\n#3 /var/www/properties/web/spo/src/Runtime/Auth/AuthenticationContext.php(69): Office365\\PHP\\Client\\Runtime\\Auth\\SamlTokenProvider->acquireToken(Array)\n#4 /var/www/properties/web/spo/index.php(11): Office365\\PHP\\Client\\Runtime\\Auth\\AuthenticationContext->ac in /var/www/properties/web/spo/src/Runtime/Utilities/Requests.php on line 34`

Being new to SharePoint in general, is this actually possible? I have yet to see a successful implementation online. Is there a detailed guide somewhere as to how Office 365 authentication works in general? I've been stuck on it for a while now and it looks like PHP/SharePoint resources are pretty sparse.

Any form of assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide some examples of code, that you are used. We need to have some concrete topic and discuss about concrete problem.

> Could not resolve host: login.microsoftonline.com

It's very strange. Maybe you have a problem with DNS.

Comment: I downloaded the API and changed its configuration by providing my own credentials to test it out on its index.php file:

`use Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\Auth\AuthenticationContext;
use Office365\PHP\Client\Runtime\Auth\OAuthTokenProvider;
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$Url = "https://myserver.sharepoint.com";
$UserName = "test_user";
$Password = "123456";

$authCtx = new AuthenticationContext($Url);
$authCtx->acquireTokenForUser($UserName,$Password); //authenticate`

(I modified the credentials here for privacy reasons)
I'm getting a 500 error when I open the page.

Comment: How php you use? mod_php, php_fpm? Could you provide logs from you webserver?

Comment: I added the error in the question above.

Comment: Please try to ping `login.microsoftonline.com` by `ping login.microsoftonline.com` command in terminal of server, where you test you program and give results.

Comment: `ping login.microsoftonline.com
Pinging aadg.windows.net.nsatc.net [65.52.193.136] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.` What does this mean?

Comment: I've got it. :) login.microsoftonline.com node cut's off almost all traffic except http (ping uses ICMP). We need to check docs and that host login.microsoftonline.com is correct host for API. May be this code example is obsolete...

Comment: It looks like it - I tried SimpleSAMLPHP but coming from a WP development background the documentation is all jargon to me. Is there a beginner-friendly reference somewhere?

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PHP-App-for-SharePoint you can try to work with that project as a base and test app. Try. After that we can discuss to solve problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it out right now but I don't understand the Composer stuff. For context I only write code on my local machine and upload them to a web server to run it. Is there a way to go around that?

Comment: I think that Composer not so hard to understand. It's simple dependency/libs manager for PHP. In our time it's standard de-facto in PHP development.

Good intro https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

If you would have any questions after reading intro feel free to ask. ;)

Comment: I'm starting to get it working now, but this time I'm getting this error whenever I try to make Composer download the dependencies: `Failed to download guzzle/guzzle from dist: You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https`. What does this mean and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You need to install php_openssl extension. If you use, for example Debian you need apt install php-openssl